# How can I return all results from one table combined with the count of a specific field of another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like this:

```
TABLE: maindata
client_id | username | data | data_id
______________________________________
0         | rusty    | xyz  | 827
1         | rusty1   | xyz  | 827
2         | rusty2   | xyz  | 827
```

And then in another table I have:

```
TABLE: users:
client_id | username |
______________________
0         | rusty    |
1         | rusty1   |
2         | rusty2   |
2         | rusty3   |
2         | rusty4   |
```

I would like to return:

```
client_id | username | data | data_id | count
______________________________________
0         | rusty    | xyz  | 827     | 1
1         | rusty1   | xyz  | 827     | 1
2         | rusty2   | xyz  | 827     | 3
```

The count here is the count for the number of clients in users. What I have tried has not gotten me where I would like at all:

> SELECT * from stats AS s INNER JOIN users as u SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE
>   u.client_id=s.client_id GROUP BY client_id

Any idea where I am going wrong? Is INNER JOIN totally wrong?

Edit : highlight query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(*) as count from stats AS s 
   INNER JOIN users as u on u.client_id=s.client_id
   GROUP BY client_id
```

Comment: My current results from this are every row in stats is being multiplied by the number of users for each client_id, any idea how to not have the number of users affect the values returning for s.*?

Comment: Aha! I needed: INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT client_ID FROM users) as u ON u.client_id=s.client_id